# How to speed up continuous fetch and save requests to core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I'm having a situation in which I have to deal with continuous fetch and save requests. My app is freezing when the amount of data I have to deal with increases. My savings are updated instantly to the tableview by `NSFetchedResultsController`. I tried to isolate my problem by using a sample code and I have put some code below. The freezing problem is in this region. I will have atleast 3000 records to save. Somebody please help me to tackle my UI freezing issue.

This is the profiler log on running the project : https://www.dropbox.com/s/tf1eiz3c5vnr0hq/Instruments10.trace.zip?dl=0

```
- (void)coreDataTest {

// Create NSManagedObjectModel and NSPersistentStoreCoordinator

NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"store.sqlite"];

// remove old store if exists

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]])

    [fileManager removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil];

NSManagedObjectModel *model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *storeCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];

[storeCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType

                               configuration:nil

                                         URL:storeURL

                                     options:nil

                                       error:nil];

NSManagedObjectContext* masterContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

[masterContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:storeCoordinator];

// create the parent NSManagedObjectContext with the concurrency type to NSMainQueueConcurrencyType

_parentContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];

[_parentContext setParentContext:masterContext];

// creat the child one with concurrency type NSPrivateQueueConcurrenyType

_childContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

[_childContext setParentContext:_parentContext];

// create a NSEntityDescription for the only entity in this CoreData model: Test

NSEntityDescription *testDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Test"

                                                   inManagedObjectContext:_parentContext];

// perform a heavy write block on the child context

__block BOOL done = NO;

[_childContext performBlock:^{

    for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++){

        Test *test = [[Test alloc] initWithEntity:testDescription

                   insertIntoManagedObjectContext:_childContext];

        test.test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test %d", i];

        NSLog(@"Create test %d", i);

        [_childContext save:nil];

    done = YES;

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSLog(@"Done write test: Saving parent");

        [_parentContext save:nil];

        NSFetchRequest *fr = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Test"];

        NSLog(@"Done: %d objects written", [[_parentContext executeFetchRequest:fr error:nil] count]);

        [masterContext performBlock:^{

            [masterContext save:nil];

        // execute a fetch request on the parent to see the results

        }];

    });

    }

}];

// execute a read request after 1 second

double delayInSeconds = 1.0;

dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);

dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

    NSFetchRequest *fr = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Test"];

    [_parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{

        NSLog(@"In between read: read %d objects", [[_parentContext executeFetchRequest:fr error:nil] count]);

    }];

});   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following steps that will improve speed

1 - Use NSFethedResultControler , it will help you to reload data automatically after every save , because its delegate is called after every save

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller{
     [self fetchCoreDataArrayAfterSave];
}
```

2 - Try to save in batches (100) at a time

3 - User insertObject method of NSMangedObjectContext instead of save ,save will be use just after insertion of 100's batch .

```
for (int i = 0; i <first 100; i++){

    Test *test = [[Test alloc] initWithEntity:testDescription

               insertIntoManagedObjectContext:_childContext];

    test.test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test %d", i];


    [_childContext insertObject:test]
 };

 [_childContext save:nil];
```

4 - do all this in background

5 - use batches to fetch data too .

If you can't understand any point feel free to ask .

Comment: I have NSFetchedResultsController implemented. That is the main hindrance for me to not saving all my data together at some comfortable time. I want to update data in the tableview each time data comes from the server.

Comment: Please see the updated post . when you will save first 100 records , then fetch these and show to tableview , in background all other saving will be going on and fetching after saving every batch too . soo you can show 100 record then user will scrool down , the time user will get to reach hundred you can get next hundred

Comment: if you are familiar with concept of Private ManagedObjectontext , this will be easy to under stand for you , and it is imposible for me to add all code here :(

Comment: I tried most of these methods. But the freezing issue was still there. When I tried to make everything in background, deadlocks came. I didn't try insertObject into moc. Will that function alone update the fetchedresultscontroller? I mean without saving?

Comment: no it will not perform saving , but you have to perform save after inserting 100 , that will save hundred , and you delegate calls you can fetch that stored results , i am searching a link for private managed object context , that will help you very much

Comment: @RSK https://github.com/mmorey/MDMHPCoreData go through this , specialy class MDMPersistenceStack and a method (batchImportWithEfficientFindOrCreateAndPeriodicSaves) of class MDMUFOSightingImportOperation, this is like a charm :P ,,, after understanding up vote this ans too :P

Answer (score 0):

For Performing Fast insert without blocking the Main Thread use the above code

//Create Parent Context In Appdelegate

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil) {
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
     [_managedObjectContext setUndoManager:nil];
}
return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

//Create Child Context In Appdelegate

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)childManagedObjectContext
{
if (_childManagedObjectContext != nil) {
    return _childManagedObjectContext;
}

_childManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

[_childManagedObjectContext setParentContext:_managedObjectContext];


return _childManagedObjectContext;
}
```

//Now Perfrom the save operation

```
[UIAppDelegate.childManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{

        //Fill Ur Daatbse (Insert)
       for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
             [UIAppDelegate.childManagedObjectContext save:nil];
        }


        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [UIAppDelegate.managedObjectContext save:nil];
            [UIAppDelegate hideProgressBar];


        });

    }];
```